# "I'm now missing" vs "now I am missing"

Tags: grammar

Which of the following two sentences is grammatically correct?

> 1. City lights now I am missing.
> 2. City lights I'm now missing.

Answer (score 1):

Kind of *neither*, in the sense that they're both sentence **fragments** and neither is a grammatically-correct full sentence. Needs more context. But #2 is a better-structured sentence fragment than #1.

Comment: It is for a song lyrics.

Comment: I kind of had a feeling that was it, based on the... I don't know, the meter, I guess? And, honestly, in that context #1 wouldn't be beyond the pale. Amazing amounts of grammatical gymnastics go on, to shoe-horn ideas into lyrics that fit the tune. (I mean, Men Without Hats rhyme "dance" with "hands", in "Safety Dance"! Those two words do not rhyme, even if you somehow pronounce "hands" as "hance".)

Comment: @millym - Please don't exclude pertinent information like that, only to add it later in the comments. That little tidbit should have been ***included in the question itself*** (you can still add it with an edit). It's quite rare to include [too many details](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/439/please-everyone-details-please) in a question; unfortunately, questions with insufficient details are all too common.

Comment: Actually, I don't think it is a sentence fragment.  It has a subject, **I**, a verb, **am missing**, and an object, **city lights**; it's just ordered unusually.

Comment: @stangdon In a sense I agree, as all of the same information could be expressed with, "I miss the city lights." which obviously is a complete sentence. But, the forms above wouldn't ever be spoken on their own as complete sentences, they're structured in such a way that they're not complete as-is. (Which is consistent with a line from a song, most _aren't_ complete sentences and seem "off" taken out of context.)

Comment: I guess two things, really, fall short of "sentencehood" for me: 1. The use of "city lights", as it feels incomplete compared to "the city lights" which is definitely an object. 2. The presence of "now", which feels superfluous unless there's additional context, another concept that it's contrasting. (e.g. _Last year_ I lived in Chicago, _now_ I miss the city lights.)